# Como pegar o parametro da url no NextJs

Tags: react, react-router, next.js

Galera, estou com uma dúvida no Next JS, tenho uma página com nome `listid.js`, ao acessar por exemplo http://localhost:3000/listid/10 eu gostaria de receber o id 10 como parametro na minha página `listid.js`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

// components

import ListUser from "components/ListUser.js";

function ListId() {
  
  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex flex-wrap mt-4">
        <div className="w-full mb-12 xl:mb-0 px-4">
          <ListUser />
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
 
}

export default ListId;
```

Segue o código do meu compomente `ListUser`:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Api from "../../services/api";
import Router from 'next/router';
import Link from "next/link";


function ListUser() {

  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    async function getItems() {
      try {
        const { data } = await Api.get("/user"); //preciso passar o parametro aqui
        setUser(data);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    }
    getItems();
  }, []);

  // console.log(users.length);
  if (users === null) {
    return <h2>Carregando...</h2>;
  }
  return (
    <>
        <div>
            {
              user?.map((user) => {
                return (
                    <p>{user.id}</p>
                )})
            }
        </div>
    </>
    );
}
export default ListUser;
```

**Como eu posso pegar o id na url e passar na requisição da api?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Para que você tenha esse formato de URL `http://localhost:3000/listid/10` basta criar dentro do diretório pages seguindo esse formato: `listid/[id].js` onde `listid` seria uma pasta com a página `[id].js` dentro.

E para recuperar o paramêtro `id` você pode utilizar o `useRouter` do próprio nextjs na página `[id].js` e acessar o objeto `query`:

```
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'

...

const { query } = useRouter()

console.log(query.id)
```

Tendo recuperado o `id` do objeto `query` você pode usa-lo normalmente para realizar a request.

Documentação oficial:

> Any route like /post/1, /post/abc, etc. will be matched by pages/post/[pid].js. The matched path parameter will be sent as a query parameter to the page, and it will be merged with the other query parameters.

Tradução

> Qualquer rota como /post/1, /post/abc, etc. será correspondida por pages/post/[pid].js. O parâmetro de caminho correspondente será enviado como um parâmetro de consulta para a página e será mesclado com os outros parâmetros de consulta.

Referências:

[Dynamic Routes](https://nextjs.org/docs/routing/dynamic-routes)

Comment: Muito obrigado Gabriel, sua explicação foi de grande ajuda, consegui fazer aqui!